# GraphQL fetch data if field equals value

Tags: graphql

I've put together a GQL query to pull address

```
    venue{
      id
      name
      description
      account{
        edges{
          node{
            postalAddresses{
                            usage 
              lines
              postcode
              city
              country {
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Which returns a list of address but I'm trying to limit the results to only show the "billing". i.e. Where usage == "billing".

But I just can't work this out! Could anyone assist please?

Thanks,
S

Comment: Filters are provided by the GraphQL server. What server URL are you hitting? Is it a public server or one that you control?

Comment: Hi, it's an public TMS provider

Comment: Then you need to read the docs for that server to find out how to do the query you want. GraphQL doesn't include native filtering/sorting capabilities, it really depends on what the server exposes.